# Passing string value with return characters to javascript function causes error

Tags: javascript

The console shows the error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL' when string values with return characters -as in the example below- are passed to the function in the simplified code below. When a string value without return characters (like 'hello world') is passed the code works fine. I don't understand why and also how to solve this?

simplified function code:

```
var showSinglePrivateMessage = function(privatemessage,wrapper){

   console.log('showSinglePrivateMessage()-theprivatemessage: '+privatemessage);

}//showSinglePrivateMessage
```

UPDATE: added the following function that calls `showSinglePrivateMessage`:

```
var s_message_private_ref = function(theprivatemessage,wrapper){
  console.log('s_message_private_ref()-theprivatemessage: '+theprivatemessage['postcontent']);   


  var testmessagecontent = theprivatemessage['postcontent'];//'een test message';
  return '<a id="myprivate_s_messagelink" href="#" onclick="userapp.showSinglePrivateMessage(\'' + testmessagecontent + '\',\'' + wrapper + '\');">'+theprivatemessage['postsubject']+'</a>';
}//message_topic_ref
```

example string value (some Dutch text;-) ) for `privatemessage` (retrieved from the database):

```
Beste Marie,

Uit onze administratie blijkt een achterstand van betaling.

Gelieve  het verschuldigde bedrag van 23.12 over te maken binnen uiterlijk 7 dagen.

Met vriendelijke groet,
Mies
Administratie
```

Comment: Can you show where the call to `showSinglePrivateMessage` is made?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Comment: Usually the line containing the syntax error is given too. I see no problems with yor code, are you sure this is the right part? What's after that?

Comment: I updated the code above with the function that calls showSinglePrivateMessage()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, depending on the content of `testmessagecontent`, you're generating Javascript code with incorrect syntax. This is usually caused by unescaped content, containing quotes or whatever, so you may resolve with something like this:

```
return '<a id="myprivate_s_messagelink" href="#" onclick="userapp.showSinglePrivateMessage(\''
       + testmessagecontent.replace(/'/g, "&#39;").replace(/"/g, "&#34;")
       + '\',\'' + wrapper + '\');">' + theprivatemessage['postsubject'] + '</a>';
```

But I really don't recommend walking this path at all. First of all, you're using traditional event registration. Would it be difficult to make `s_message_private_ref` return a DOM element instead of a raw HTML string?

Because this would be much cleaner:

```
var s_message_private_ref = function(theprivatemessage, wrapper) {
    console.log('s_message_private_ref()-theprivatemessage: '
            + theprivatemessage['postcontent']);   

    var testmessagecontent = theprivatemessage['postcontent'], //'een test message'
        anchor = document.createElement("a");

    anchor.id = "myprivate_s_messagelink";
    anchor.href = "#";
    anchor.innerHTML = theprivatemessage['postsubject'];
    anchor.addEventListener("click", function() {
        userapp.showSinglePrivateMessage(testmessagecontent, wrapper);
    });
    return anchor;
}//message_topic_ref
```

You're maybe using `s_message_private_ref` to append an element to some container. This way, instead of appending a string (you're not using `.innerHTML += ...`, don't you? Because DON'T!), you append a DOM element.

Keep in mind that `addEventListener` isn't supported by IE8 and lower, so you either test for `attachEvent` or use some framework that does the job for you, like jQuery.

Also, consider event delegation.

Finally, are you sure about assigning a fixed ID to a user generated element?

Comment: ok, thanx for the elaborate explenation (!) will give it a try